# What makes an object assignment-compatible with another class?

Tags: java, inheritance, casting

I'm wondering what specifically allows an object of one class to be cast as another class.  Looking at the Class.isInstance(Object obj) [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance(java.lang.Object)), it suggests that an object has to be 'assignment-compatible' with another class in order to be cast to that class.  But what constitutes 'assignment-compatible'?

I'm trying to figure out how the following returned a ClassCastException:

```
public class A
{
    multiple private attributes
    No constructor
    multiple public methods
}

public class B extends A
{
    blank default constructor
    2 additional private attributes
    4 additional public getter / setter methods for these attributes
}
```

The line

```
B b = (B)variable.getA()  // where getA() returned an instance of class A
```

returns a ClassCastException A cannot be cast as B.  I know that casting from a parent class to a subclass is a bad idea.  I did not write the code in question, I'm just looking at it in a production support capacity.

Class B is the only class in the codebase that extends from A.  So the result of getA() is not an object of another subclass of A (say C) cast to A.

So why in this instance can Java not cast an object of class A to the seemingly compatible class B?

Comment: _leads Java to believe_ Java doesn't need to guess. It knows what the type of an object is. If it's an instance of concrete type `A`, then it isn't `B`.

Comment: Thanks Sotirios.  I have re-phrased the last sentence to hopefully summarize a bit better.  Both A and B have the same attributes and methods, with B having a couple of additional ones.  Therefore you would think that an object of class B could be created using the attributes of the object of class A with the default values of class B used for the extra attributes.  This question is aimed at helping me understand why they appear to be compatible, but in reality are not.

Comment: What is your definiton of 'compatible'.　 A and B are look similar in the view as A, but B has something extra. Instance of A could not work as B, because that instance has not 'samething extra' which only B has. In other words, B can be cast as A, because 'B extends A' as you declared in your code.

Comment: When I say compatible, I mean able to be cast to.  So you are saying that A cannot be cast to B because B has two extra attributes?  I thought these would be set as null or their default values?  In my case, the class definition of B does have default values for both additional attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javadoc for [Class.isInstance(Object obj)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance(java.lang.Object)) gives the definition of `assignment compatible`:

> Specifically, **if this Class object represents a declared class, this method returns true if the specified Object argument is an instance of the represented class (or of any of its subclasses)**; it returns false otherwise. If this Class object represents an array class, this method returns true if the specified Object argument can be converted to an object of the array class by an identity conversion or by a widening reference conversion; it returns false otherwise. **If this Class object represents an interface, this method returns true if the class or any superclass of the specified Object argument implements this interface**; it returns false otherwise. If this Class object represents a primitive type, this method returns false.

Basically,  you can assign an object of type A to variable of type B if type A extends or implements type B.

Comment: Thanks Ricardo.  This is the sort of answer I was looking for.  It seems strange though that this code a)Compiles b) seems to work ok in 99% of cases.  So I thought it might be something a bit more complex like matching methods and attributes etc.

Answer (score 2):

Consider these two cases:

```
A a = new B();
B b = (B)a;    <--  Ok.

A a = new A();
B b = (B)a;    <--  ClassCastException
```

So in order to cast an object to B it must be an instance of B (or a subclass of B).

In your case it is however an instance of A.

Answer (score 0):

Thrown to indicate that the code has attempted to cast an object to a subclass of which it is not an instance. For example, the following code generates a `ClassCastException`:

```
 Object x = new Integer(0);
 System.out.println((String)x);
```

more info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html) and [here](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/01/26/classloading.html?page=1).

Comment: This dose not address the core question "What makes an object 'assignment-compatible' with another class" and the example is not relevant as the two classes are similar, rather than consisting of different types like Integer / String.

Answer (score 0):

If we replaced A and B with meaningful names that help us think about the problem, then the answer becomes clearer. If A becomes Mammal and B is Dog, then we can reasonably say that all Dogs are Mammals, but we cannot say that all Mammals are Dogs. Even if they superficially shared the same attributes, there is no guarantee that all Mammals would fulfill the contract of being a Dog, and the compiler shouldn't try to assume so.

Comment: But dosen't the compiler allow this because there is the possibility that Mammal _might_ be able to fulfill the contract of being a Dog?  And in my case this is highly likely.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add the official specification to support 
[Ricardo's correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25861845/2513200) that "you can assign an object of type A to variable of type B if type A extends or implements type B":

The JLS defines assignment-compatibility as follows:

[5.2. Assignment Contexts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2)

> If the type of an expression can be converted to the type of a variable by assignment conversion, we say the expression (or its value) is assignable to the variable or, equivalently, that the type of the expression is assignment compatible with the type of the variable.

The term **"assingment conversion"** is only defined as applying the appropriate conversion from the list given in the "Assignment Contexts"-chapter:

> The term "conversion" is also used to describe, without being specific, any conversions allowed in a particular context. For example, we say that an expression that is the initializer of a local variable is subject to "assignment conversion", meaning that a specific conversion will be implicitly chosen for that expression according to the rules for the assignment context.

The most relevant for reference types being

[5.1.5. Widening Reference Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.5)

> A widening reference conversion exists from any reference type S to any reference type T, provided S is a subtype of T (§4.10).

Subtypes include implemented interfaces (see [4.10.2. Subtyping among Class and Interface Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.2) ).

There are additional rules for numeric and generic types, but they are not relevant for the example given in the question.